# Changing button colour everytime button is pressed kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I would like my button to turn from blue to green when it is pressed. I would then like it to turn from green back to blue if it is pressed again. I know how to change the colour of a button when pressed but I don't know how to change that colour back to the original colour if the button is pressed again.

kv file:

```
<Type>:
    name: "type"
        RoundedButton:
            size_hint: 0.417, 0.15625
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.0556, "y": 0.15}
            on_press: root.change_color()
            Image:
                source: 'Job.PNG'
                size: self.parent.width, .85 * self.parent.height
                pos: self.parent.x, self.parent.y + 5
                stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False

<RoundedButton@Button>:
    background_normal: ""
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
    back_color: 0.2,0.6,1,1
    border_radius: 10
    color: self.back_color
    bold: True
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.back_color
        Line:
            rounded_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, self.border_radius
            width:
```

python file:

```
class Type(Screen):
    back_color = ObjectProperty()
    def change_color(self):
        if self.back_color == (0.2,0.6,1,1):
            self.back_color = (0, 1, 0, 1)
        else:
            self.back_color = (0.2,0.6,1,1)
```

I thought the logic I had in the py file would check if the colour is blue (0.2,0.6,1,1), i.e not pressed, it would turn green and if it wasn't blue (so must be green, it would turn blue. However when I press the button nothing happens, there's no error, it just doesn't turn green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple problems.

First, your `change_color()` method is trying to change the `back_color` in your `Type` instance, but your `RoundedButton` rule is referencing the `back_color` in your `RoundedButton` instance (not the one in the `Type`). So any changes that the method makes, will not affect the `RoundedButton`.

Second, the `if` statement:

```
if self.back_color == (0.2,0.6,1,1):
```

will never be True. Partly because of the first problem, but also the comparison needs to be:

```
if self.back_color == [0.2,0.6,1,1]:
```

I'm not sure why that is.

I think the asiest way to fix the first problem is to add an `id` to the `RoundedButton`:

```
<Type>:
    name: "type"
    RoundedButton:
        id: butt
        size_hint: 0.417, 0.15625
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.0556, "y": 0.15}
        on_press: root.change_color()
```

Then modify the `change_color()` method to:

```
class Type(Screen):
    def change_color(self):
        if self.ids.butt.back_color == [0.2,0.6,1,1]:
            self.ids.butt.back_color = (0, 1, 0, 1)
        else:
            self.ids.butt.back_color = (0.2,0.6,1,1)
```

Note that the `back_color` `ObjectProperty` is not needed.

If you want the `RoundedButtons` to be independently changing color, you can define your `RoundedButton` as:

```
class RoundedButton(Button):
    back_color = ListProperty()

    def change_color(self):
        if self.back_color == [0.2,0.6,1,1]:
            self.back_color = [0, 1, 0, 1]
        else:
            self.back_color = [0.2,0.6,1,1]
```

And in your `kv` file:

```
<Type>:
    name: "type"
    RoundedButton:
        size_hint: 0.417, 0.15625
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.0556, "y": 0.15}
        Image:
            source: 'Job.PNG'
            size: self.parent.width, .85 * self.parent.height
            pos: self.parent.x, self.parent.y + 5
            stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
    RoundedButton:
        size_hint: 0.417, 0.15625
        pos_hint: {"right": 1, "top": 1}
        Image:
            source: 'Job.PNG'
            size: self.parent.width, .85 * self.parent.height
            pos: self.parent.x, self.parent.y + 5
            stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False

<RoundedButton>:
    background_normal: ""
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
    back_color: 0.2,0.6,1,1
    border_radius: 10
    color: self.back_color
    bold: True
    on_press: self.change_color()
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.back_color
        Line:
            rounded_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, self.border_radius
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I've got multiple RoundedButtons on the same screen that I'd like exactly the same effect for. Do I need to give the Id:butt to the Button they inherit from (RoundedButton@Button) rather than the indivudal button I've done above? I could just test this out but won't be at my computer for a couple of days now and eager to know

Comment: @John Anderson
The comparison is not working because color in Kivy Language is a ListProperty . And in here `if self.back_color == (0.2,0.6,1,1)` you check if a list == tuple that will always return false.
Also on your assignment you should also use a list not a tuple. It is working, but can cause problems latter.

Comment: You cannot put the `id` in the `<RoundedButton@Button>`, any `id` is added to a dictionary in the root of the rule, and in this case the `RoundedButton` is the root of that rule. Also, you can only have one object with a specific `id`. If you want this effect for several `Buttons` (that change color independently), then you should define your own subclass of `RoundedButton` that has a `back_color` property, and a `change_color()` method. Then your `on_press` would be more like `on_press: self.change_color()`. And some appropriate changes to `change_color()`.

Comment: I have added to my original answer to demonstrate my above comment.

Comment: Thanks for the help both of you, I understand it now and can see how I can set an on press event that links to my python logic and apply it to all instances of that button/widget.